# How to solve thread blocking in Py.test?

Tags: pytest, python-multithreading

I am using Py.test to implement integration testing for uploading photos into Picasa. However, the authentication method from `oauth2client.flow_from_clientsecrets` (that should open a web-browser to authentication URL), simply stopped.

I am not sure about why it occur though, is it because from py.test we can't create/span new process? This is because `oauth2client.flow_from_clientsecrets` will call `webbrowser.open` that in turn will call `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: There's no reason for that not to work because of `py.test`. Can you reproduce your problem in a minimal example?

Comment: That's a good insight. Correct. Lemme try this. Hm, actually, I am testing a kivy application using https://github.com/eviltnan/kivy-autotesting-example. I was thinking this is because there is Kivy main loop of the application. Got to confirm this to make sure

Comment: Okay, checked with flickrapi (I am also testing Flickr authentication), with minimal py script, http://pastebin.com/wFnTDDk0, it stop at line 22, when it should open the browser to flickr auth URL. And the line is about `if not webbrowser.open_new_tab(url):`. So, .. how do I avoid blocking of app when testing a `webbrowser.open` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bruno Oliveira is right. I try to use a clean py.test to test flickr/picasa auth, and it's able to open a web-browser. The problem may lies in other custom library that being developed.

Thanks!

PS: I will report it here if I found why `webbrowser.open` won't work

Comment: Glad to hear. I think you can accept your own answer then and close this question. :)